# SQL syntax error when adding a user to the database through php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to add a user through my admin control panel on my php webpage, and i get this error. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax` I cannot seem to spot the problem for the life of me, here is the full page code.

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<?php include ("db.php"); ?>
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
        $Username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $sex = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sex']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $passwordmd5 = md5($password);

        $sql="INSERT INTO `username` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `name`, `dob`, `sex`, `phone`, `imagelink`, `coverimage`, `hobby`, `Bio`) VALUES ('$_POST[Username]','$passwordmd5','$_POST[email]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[dob]','$_POST[sex]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[imagelink]','$_POST[coverpicture]'),'$_POST[hobby]','$_POST[bio]'";

        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        include ("addition_successful.php");
        exit();
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Network TV - Add Record</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Network TV Add new user</h1>
        <br>
        <div class="toolbar">
            <a href="data_display.php">Return to the main page</a>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <h2>User details</h2>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
            <p>Username:</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" placeholder="Input Username here ... "></p>
            <p>password:</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Input password here ... "></p>
            <p>email:</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Input Email address  here ... "></p>
            <p>Name:</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Input name here ... "></p>
            <p>Date of birth:</p>
            <p><input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="Input date of birth here ... "></p>
            <p>Gender:</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="sex" id="sex" placeholder="Input gender here ... "></p>
            <p>Phone Number:</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Input phone number here ... "></p>
            <p>Profile Picture:</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="imagelink" id="imagelink" placeholder="Input profile picture link here ... "></p>
            <p>Cover Picture:</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="coverpicture" id="coverpicture" placeholder="Input cover picture link here ... "></p>
            <p>Hobbys:</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="hobby" id="hobby" placeholder="Input hobbys here ... "></p>
            <p>Bio:</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="bio" id="bio" placeholder="Input bio here ... "></p>



            <p><input type="submit" name="create" value="Create New Record"></p>
        </form>
        <div class="separator"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The session.php is just to create a session when the user logs in, and the db is just the database connection for Mysql.

**Update**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''None','None'' at line 1
```

Comment: Show the whole error message. Also, you are wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: im aware that im open to SQL injections, this will just be a site for my family on the home network, but thanks, none of them understands IT so I should be fine? il update the question to add the error message

Comment: What basic steps would I take to protect myself? I have mysql_real_escape_string on most of the inputs and things

Comment: That's the kicker. You didn't use the variables you assigned those sanitized values to. Start by *using* them instead of the raw $_POST data.

Comment: Wait, im confused, first what do you mean by thats the kicker :D and I escaped the string so dont they just escape in the variable then i use it normally? I dunno Ill research it more tomorrow

Comment: No i have $sql="INSERT INTO `username` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `name`, `dob`, `sex`, `phone`, `imagelink`, `coverimage`, `hobby`, `Bio`) VALUES ('$Username','$passwordmd5','$email','$name','$dob','$sex','$phone','$imagelink','$coverpicture','$hobby','$bio')"; is that correct?

Comment: I was confused why I made those variables, then never used them without POST, i'm a newb at this though :D will that protect me against SQL injections then for that page, I can do the rest of the other pages in the same manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closing `)` is in the wrong place:

```
'$_POST[coverpicture]'),'$_POST[hobby]','$_POST[bio]'";
                   ^^^^^
                    HERE
```

Move it to the end of your VALUES:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `username` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `name`, `dob`, `sex`, `phone`, `imagelink`, `coverimage`, `hobby`, `Bio`) VALUES ('$_POST[Username]','$passwordmd5','$_POST[email]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[dob]','$_POST[sex]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[imagelink]','$_POST[coverpicture]','$_POST[hobby]','$_POST[bio]')";
```

Comment: Fixed, thanks man, you will not believe how long i have been staring at this code tying to figure it out :D all fixed, perfect! I cannot mark your answer correct for 9 minutes, so I will do it later, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error in your SQL is that you arbitrarily end your `VALUES()` array and then pass further parameters, observe:

```
'$_POST[coverpicture]'),'$_POST[hobby]','$_POST[bio]'";
```

Change that to :

```
'$_POST[coverpicture]','$_POST[hobby]','$_POST[bio]')";
```

Further, accepting unsecaptd user input data is considered insecure and should be replaced with prepared statements.

Lastly, the `mysql_` library is deprecated. Please consider moving to at least `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: Thanks for the heady up, I know nothing about either of those two, but a quick question is mysqli similar to Mysql, will I have to rewrite all of my code?

Comment: mysqli is very similar to mysql. you will notice small nuances here and there that you will need to change. but overall, for procedural, very easy.

Comment: Okay, so why is the change needed? i have only been coding html css and mysql for a month or so. I'm super new to all this!

Answer (score 0):

The `)` is in a wrong place:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `username` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `name`, `dob`, `sex`, `phone`, `imagelink`, `coverimage`, `hobby`, `Bio`) VALUES ('$_POST[Username]','$passwordmd5','$_POST[email]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[dob]','$_POST[sex]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[imagelink]','$_POST[coverpicture]','$_POST[hobby]','$_POST[bio]')";
```

Comment: Thanks mate, someone just said it before you, but I appreciate the help!